# Systemd Initrd service and persistence

Tags: debian, systemd

I need to run a simple daemon from system initrd image. According to system.initrd documentation, when systemd is running directly from initrd all running processes will be killed on `switch-root`, unless `argv[0][0]` character of main process is `@`. The only way I found to change `argv[0]` it to add proper statement in application source code, but unfortunately this is a proprietary software and I do not have access to its source code. I also found that shell `exec` command can run process under different name, changing it `argv[0]` parameter, so I wrote simple service file for systemd using `exec` to deploy new process and it works, `ps aux` shows that service process is running under proper name (`@bin/process-name ...`). Like mentioned before, processes with `argv[0]` starting with `@` character shouldn't be killed on `switch-root`.

My systemd recipe:

```
[Unit]
Description=Simple service

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'exec -a "@bin/process-name" /bin/application'
```

I make sure that this service is working before `switch-root` by manually enabled it at initrd stage, but it is killed like any other running processes. I tried running it as normal application, but that's not working either. I even wrote my own application which changes their `argv[0][0]` to `@`, and like before it is killed on `switch-root`. So, how to run persistent service from initrd? It seems that systemd  kills ALL processes during `switch-root` leaving nothing behind, even special processes which shouldn't be killed.

```
Initrd: Dracut
OS: Debian Jessie
Systemd version: 208-8
```

Source: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/RootStorageDaemons/

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by using this??  Systemd kills all running processes because you are changing the mountpoint for `/` on a running system. [Switch_Root manpage](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman8/switch_root.8.html)